# Searching a txt file for a line and deleting the subsequent 13 lines in a batch file

Tags: string, text, batch-file, line

I have some txt files that I need a batch file to search for a specific line and then delete that line and the subsequent 13 lines from the txt file.

and example of the txt file is:

```
<section1>
line1
line2
line3

<section2>
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

<section3>
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8

etc.
```

The line i would need to search for is `<section2>` and then delete the following:

```
<section2>
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

So ending up with:

```
<section1>
line1
line2
line3

<section3>
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8

etc.
```

I would also need to edit some lines after the other sections, for example edit `line1` in `<section3>` to say `editline1`

So it would find the `<section3>` string and alter line 1 to appear as below

```
<section3>
editline1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
```

Thanks

Comment: I would use awk for this. From the [GNU Awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) description:  _Several kinds of tasks occur repeatedly when working with text files. You might want to extract certain lines and discard the rest. Or you may need to make changes wherever certain patterns appear, but leave the rest of the file alone..._

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
  set fnam="%~1"
  set outnam="%~dpn1.out"
  set search4="%~2"
  set section=.
  for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('type %fnam%') do call :work %fnam% "%%x"
  MOVE /Y %outnam% %fnam%
goto :eof

:work
  set "line=%~2"
  if "%line:~0,1%%line:~-1%"=="<>" (
    if "%section%" neq "." echo.>> %outnam%
    set "section=^%line:~,-1%^>"
    set "line=^%line:~,-1%^>"
  )
  if NOT "%section:~1,-2%>"==%search4% echo %line%>> %outnam%
```

Call it like this:

```
section filename.txt "<section2>"
```